# UI issues with ionic application

Tags: android, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm really not sure what's happening but when the user input field is active, logo and other content on the screen disappear. Is this something to do with the scss file of the page? Please help.

This is the sccs file of the page:

```
.page-main {

 .image {  
    display:block;
    height: 40%;
    width: auto; 
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }

 .login {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 8%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;   
 }

 .register {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 8%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
 }

 .fgtpwd {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 8%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }

}
```

This is the html file:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="page-main">
  <img src="assets/img/logo.png" class="image"/>
    <ion-item>
     <ion-label color="primary" floating>Email</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]=user.email></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]=user.password></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
     <button class="login" (click)="login(user)" ion-button round medium icon-end color="primary">
        {{ loginMsg }}
        <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
     </button>
     <button class="register" (click)="reg()" ion-button item-end clear medium color="primary">
        {{ regMsg }}
     </button>
     <button class="fgtpwd" (click)="forgtpwd()" ion-button clear medium color="primary">
        {{ fgtpwd }}
     </button>
</ion-content>
```

I wasn't sure if the sccs file is good enough to resize the logo and content based on the screen size and resolution.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the related code on `SCSS` file?

Comment: @Sampath I edited the question and added the sccs and html codes. I would like to edit the code so that keyboard will overlay the content of the app page and user will be able to scroll down/up to view the content covered by the keyboard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `min-height` as shown below for your page's content.

```
.page-main{
   min-height: 100%;
}
```